# JComboBox covers other things?

Tags: java, jcombobox, paintcomponent

After clicking on the JComboBox, JComboBox covers up some parts of the painting with grey rectangular shaped thing, is there something wrong with the code and how do I fix it? Thanks!

[Here's the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmhp5.png)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MouseButtonTester extends JFrame implements     MouseMotionListener{
    int x,y,r;
    JComboBox colorChooser;
    Color color;
    JTextField red = new JTextField();
    JTextField green = new JTextField();
    JTextField blue = new JTextField();
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JComboBox pen;
    int fillKind;

    Object[] chooseRGB = {
        "Red: ", red, 
        "Green: ", green,
        "Blue: ", blue
    };


    public MouseButtonTester(){
    super();
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setResizable(true);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    colorChooser = new JComboBox();
    pen = new JComboBox();
    topPanel.add(pen);
    topPanel.add(colorChooser);
    colorChooser.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pen.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    pen.addItem("Pen");
    pen.addItem("Marker");
    pen.addItem("Highlighter");
    pen.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(pen.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Pen")){
                fillKind = 0;
                r = 8;
            }else if(pen.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Marker")){
                fillKind = 0;
                r = 15;
            }else if(pen.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Highlighter")){
                fillKind = 1;

            }
        }
    });

    colorChooser.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14));
    colorChooser.addItem("Red");
    colorChooser.addItem("Orange");
    colorChooser.addItem("Yellow");
    colorChooser.addItem("Green");
    colorChooser.addItem("Blue");
    colorChooser.addItem("Violet");
    colorChooser.addItem("Purple");
    colorChooser.addItem("Choose RGB");
    colorChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if("Red" == colorChooser.getSelectedItem().toString()){
                color = Color.RED;
            }else if("Orange" == colorChooser.getSelectedItem().toString()){
                color = Color.ORANGE;
            }else if("Yellow" == colorChooser.getSelectedItem().toString()){
                color = Color.YELLOW;
            }
            else if("Green" == colorChooser.getSelectedItem().toString()){
                color = Color.GREEN;
            }
            else if("Blue" == colorChooser.getSelectedItem().toString()){
                color = Color.BLUE;
            }
            else if("Violet" == colorChooser.getSelectedItem().toString()){
                color = new Color(180,0,200);
            }
            else if("Purple" == colorChooser.getSelectedItem().toString()){
                color = new Color(150,0,200);
            }
            else if("Purple" == colorChooser.getSelectedItem().toString()){

            }
            else if("Choose RGB" ==     colorChooser.getSelectedItem().toString()){
                int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, chooseRGB,        "Choose RGB", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                        int redValue = Integer.parseInt(red.getText());
                        int greenValue = Integer.parseInt(green.getText());
                        int blueValue = Integer.parseInt(blue.getText());
                        color = new Color(redValue,greenValue,blueValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } 

    Graphics graphics;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        graphics = g.create();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();

        graphics.setColor(color);
        if(fillKind == 0){
            graphics.fillOval(x, y, r, r);
        }else if(fillKind == 1){
            graphics.fillRect(x, y, 10, 25);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        //No actions
    }   
}
```

Comment: Guessing: does it make a difference if you fully configure your combo box before you add the box to its owning panel?

Comment: This is not complete; there is no `main()`, and when I add a `main()` and run it, it produces a collapsed window, not like the one you give in your image. So whatever produces that image, it is not exactly this code.

Comment: Looking at it again, I see no code to handle the case of the comboBox drop-down obscuring part of your panel and getting repainted. You will need code that does that. There is an event (I forget which one) that notifies your panel that something has obscured it, with the rectangle coordinates that have been obscured, and it is up to your panel to repaint that portion.

Comment: So how exactly can I do this?

Comment: Also forgot to state, I have main() in another class.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code carefully, the JComboBox drawn on JPanel it means drawn on drawing area.Simple way to fix this issue create two panel ; first one for tools (combobox)and add your other tools on, and another panel to drawing area.

Another way is after item choosed repaint your panel.